# A/B test for statistical significance

Tags: statistical-inference

I'm running an a/b test on an advertisement and I'd like to test for statistical significance.
How would I design a test and prove whether or not conversions/clicks are statistically different from test A and test B?

Test A: 1000 clicks, 900 conversions

Test B: 380 clicks, 320 conversions

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different answer here earlier, but now I'm pretty sure it was wrong.  There are [numerous](http://www.usereffect.com/split-test-calculator) [online](http://www.thumbtack.com/labs/abba/) [calculators](http://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/chi-squared.html) for determining whether or not results like these are statistically significant.  They all seem to use a form of [Chi squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_squared_test).

So the answer to your question is: Don't design a new test for this purpose.  Use what appears to be the standard test (Chi squared).

Comment: P values are usually treated under roughly these cutoffs: .1-.08 slight significant evidence(S.E) against the null hypothesis(N.H), .08-.05 some S.E against the N.H, .05-.02 strong S.E against the N.H, <.02 Very strong S.E. against the N.H.

I would consider this to be 'some' evidence.

Comment: @DisplayName Sorry to deprive your comment of context.  I'm pretty sure the p-value from my old answer was incorrect anyway since it didn't agree with any of the online calculators.